# Would my effects cover my partner's GY as well as mine in a Tag Duel?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Basically, if you and your tag partner both use Dragon Decks, would their effects cover your partner's GY as well?

Answer (score 1):

> Basically, if you and your tag partner both use Dragon Decks, would their effects cover your partner's GY as well?

From the [wiki page](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Tag-Team_Duel) on Tag Team Duels we have, emphasis mine:

> When taking part in a Tag-Team Duel, both teams consist of 2 players. **Players share** a combined **Life Point total** and their **fields** and **Graveyards**.

So yes, you and your partner share graveyards.

Here's also a [link](https://www.yugioh-card.com/en/league/dueling/tag_dueling.html) to the Official Tag Duel Rulings, for reference.

Comment: Thank you. I'm a fanfic writer and I like to use factual information in the duels for most things. With only minor changes for cards that I prefer the Anime effects of.

Comment: @PaulRhodes no problem glad I could help. Consider accepting this answer if it satisfied your question so other users are aware of it.